# XML Serialization with Children

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize some objects that are derived from some library code, and I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish this without touching the library (this is not managed by me).

This is the basic scenario, with the objects replaced. Basket and fruit are both library classes, and all baskets have an array of fruits.

```
class MyBasket : Basket
{
    public MyBasket () : base () { ... }
}

class Apple : Fruit
{
    public Apple () : base () { ... }
}
```

MyBasket will serialize fine by itself, but when i add an Apple and try to serialize I get the following error:

```
There was an error generating the XML document.
The type Fruit[] may not be used in this context.
```

I also sometimes see the error that tells me to use XMLInclude on the Fruit class, which I can't do.

Comment: Are you using any serializable attributes in your class..? [Serializable]
public class SomeClass
{
}

Comment: @DJ KRAZE No, all of the serializable attributes come from the base class, my class is just to add some custom functionality

Comment: Can you post a small but complete example including serialization code?

Comment: where is the serialization portion of your code..???

Answer (score 1):

If you can't touch the library and the library classes aren't set-up properly for serialization - then I don't think you're going to accomplish what you want under the current restrictions. You'll either need to:

1. Modify the library classes
2. Create your own classes that mirror the library's classes but implement the serialization properly (and then copy from the library classes to your own classes and serialize)